# Sorting multiple columns in excel via xlwt for python

Tags: python, excel, xlwt

I'm using python to write a report which is put into an excel spreadshet.

There are four columns, namely:

Product Name | Previous Value | Current Value | Difference

When I am done putting in all the values I then want to sort them based on Current Value. Is there a way I can do this in xlwt? I've only seen examples of sorting a single column.

Comment: Why not sort it in python, then write to excel?

Comment: It's the way I'm getting the data. I'm writing the data as I receive it. Figured it would be easy to just sort it once written seeing as the code already writes it to excel.

Comment: Well the issue I see with that is this, ```xlwt``` can only write, so if you write as you receive, you write it unsorted.  You would then have to pick up the data with ```xlrd```, convert it to a ```xlwt``` object with ```xlutils```, sort it, then write it again.    I don't know of any tool in python-excel which would allow you just sort it

Comment: I'll confess I'm new to Python, and am somewhat experienced with SQL. So please forgive my seemingly simple questions. We're getting data via SQL for the report. Currently, at recommendation of my boss, we're doing separate queries for the current and previous values (which are sums). 

I'm thinking it might be better to do it in one query. I assume I would use sub queries for that?

Answer (score -1):

You will get data from queries, right? Then you will write them to an excel by `xlwt`. Just before writing, you can sort them. If you can show us your code, then maybe I can optimize them. Otherwise, you have to follow wnnmaw's advice, do it in a more complicate way.

Comment: This is not really answer that will help other people.
How do one do the sort on an xlwt in-memory table prior to the save() ?
Teach a man to fish...